# mod_rewrite working but php pages not found or not recognized (downloaded instead of executed)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, php, apache-http-server, mod-rewrite

In regard to my first post [mod_rewrite problems in sandbox: Mac OSX 10.6.6 Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3](https://superuser.com/questions/486505/) I am making progress but...

Now the index.php page is not recognized or PHP is not executing. Here is the error message for this page (http://localhost/~nino/mod_rewrite_test/page/somepage):

```
Not Found
The requested URL /Users/nino/Sites/mod_rewrite_test/index.php was not found on this server.
```

If I just go to the directory, in my browser, (http://localhost/~nino/mod_rewrite_test/) the php page is downloaded, not executed.

This only happens in this directory that I have a custom conf file for mod_rewrite (/etc/apache2/users/nino.conf):

```
<Directory "/Users/nino/Sites/mod_rewrite_test">
        Options All -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here is my .htaccess file for the mod_rewrite_test directory:

```
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

Mac OSX 10.6.6 Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3

Comment: Have you [enabled PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293484/easiest-way-to-activate-php-and-mysql-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard-10-7-lion) in the Apache configuration file?

Comment: yes--------------------------